# How can I get feedback when upload file fails?

Tags: php, file-upload

I call upload.php where I perform various tasks. When something fails, I get no respons.
When I try to enter `echo "something"` I get no output.

How can I get output from the upload.php file?
I've tested using normal file upload and using uploadify.

Comment: What is your upload.php file doing? Post some code.

Comment: For uploadify if php is empty (headers didn't send) it same ass error. As I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy without posted code.

Its possible that your upload script is dying on the failure of an upload. Check for this. Also Check Folder permissions if on a UNIX platform. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want feedback if something breaks in your code, your best approach is to use `try`/`catch` in PHP.

Very simply the thinking is "try something" and "catch" the error:

```
<?php
try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    // you could also send an email notification here, wrapped in its own try/catch in case of mail failure.
}
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Will this 'echo' the output so I can see it in e.g. Firebug? Currently I've made a solution where I use `ob_start()` and save the output to a log file `$output = ob_get_contents(); $log->write($output);`

Comment: Then do that.. put it in a log file, as stated the `catch` element is used for catching exceptions, if you choose to log at this point to `$log->write($output);` it should work (unless that fails)